# What font is used to substitute

Tags: fonts, substitution

In windows OS,
is there anyway to find out a Font doesn't contain a particular character?
How can we find out which font can be used to subsititute this font to render the character?

Appreciate.

Comment: How about a bit more context? What programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a question mark is used, that is, when the Windows API's are used to render the font.

You can use Arial Unicode MS as a substitute. It is available on all modern Windows and contains a very large number of unicode characters.

Comment: I am using C#. I would like to have similar behavior like Microsoft word. When user changes font, it will only change when the font contains the character, otherwise the font will not change.